# RHEL8 and docker-compose default network error EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: docker-compose, rhel, ehostunreach

We have been using single container Docker images for some time without issues on RHEL8.  We need to move toward integrating multiple services using docker-compose but have not been successful in even simple attempts.

We are using Mongo (mongo:4.2.3-bionic) and NodeJS (node:alpine).

We created a simple node application which is trying to add a single document to a MongoDB collection.  The code for dbwrite.js is:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/", function(err, mongodb) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var mongodbo = mongodb.db("test");
  var doc = {"payload":"test doc"};
  mongodbo.collection("test2").insertOne(doc, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  mongodb.close();
});
```

The Dockerfile for dbwrite.js is:

```
FROM node:alpine
ADD . /
CMD ["node", "dbwrite.js"]
```

The Mongo container was pulled from DockerHub as was the Node container.

The docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.3-bionic
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - ./mongo_db:/data/db

app:
  image: dbwrite:v0.1
  container_name: dbwrite
```

If we perform "docker-compose up" the dbwrite container throws an error:

```
dbwrite  | /node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/server.js:233
dbwrite  |             throw err;
dbwrite  |             ^
dbwrite  | 
dbwrite  | MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error:    connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.22.0.2:27017
dbwrite  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
dbwrite  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
dbwrite  |   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
dbwrite  | }]
dbwrite  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
dbwrite  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:321:20)
dbwrite  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
dbwrite  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11
dbwrite  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7
dbwrite  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
dbwrite  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
dbwrite  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:428:26)
dbwrite  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
dbwrite  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8) {
dbwrite  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
dbwrite  |   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
dbwrite  | }
dbwrite exited with code 1
```

Rebuilding the container (doing it the hard way -- I know -- but wanting to keep everything as identical as possible), and replacing the Dockerfile CMD line

```
CMD ["node", "dbwrite.js"]
```

with

```
CMD ["ping", "-c", "20", "mongo"]
```

yields normal ping responses from "mongo" so I believe the default network was created right and the DNS is happening as expected, yet my node application gets EHOSTUNREACH.

```
dbwrite  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
dbwrite  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
dbwrite  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
dbwrite  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
dbwrite  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms
dbwrite  | 
dbwrite  | --- mongo ping statistics ---
dbwrite  | 20 packets transmitted, 20 packets received, 0% packet loss
dbwrite  | round-trip min/avg/max = 0.065/0.086/0.121 ms
dbwrite exited with code 0
```

If we edit the dbwrite.js code and replace, "mongo" in the connect() method with "localhost" and execute "node dbwrite.js" from the localhost (outside a container), the Document to the Collection.  The Mongo container log reports that it is listening on 0.0.0.0.

```
mongo    | 2020-02-10T19:35:26.337+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
mongo    | 2020-02-10T19:35:26.337+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

While I don't have the output captured, previous executions of "docker network inspect" showed both containers and their assigned IPv4 addresses on 172.22.0.x/16.  IPAM showed using the default driver "bridge" on subnet 172.22.0.0/16 and a gateway of 172.22.0.1.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated.  We are on the verge of down-grading off RHEL8 to see if that is related to our problem given that Red Hat so vocally claims **NOT** to support Docker.  Seems like it is some network security issue since ICMP ping can traverse the bridge but TCP socket connection cannot.